# Isogenous elliptic curves in characteristic zero and in characteristic $p$

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogenies

Assume two elliptic curves (with CM), $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$, are isogenous over a field $K$ of characteristic zero. Are the following two statements true?

(a) Their $V_{p}$ modules are $G_{K}$-isomorphic for every prime $p$? (I am assuming yes, from Lang's book, pg.205).

(b) Does (a) imply that these two curves remain isogenous in characteristic $p$ for every prime $p$ as long as their reductions $\overline{E_{1}}, \overline{E_{2}}$ are ordinary elliptic curves?